# Debug XQuery Program

Tags: debugging, xquery

In the beginning, I wrote a little XQuery script that was designed to do a small task and only that. Now it came out that this XQuery script is anything but complete, and I have to fix it. The problem is, my XQuery evolved into a program, and XQuery is a Pain to debug. Something that I would need would be:

Print something to the command line to check whether the program has the correct nodes at that time.

A debugging tool that shows me the stored variables

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for specific recomendations and links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Something that I would need would be:
>
> print something to the command line to
>   check weather the progroms has the
>   correct nodes at that time.

**Use the standard XPath 2.0 function [`trace()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-trace).**

> a debugging tool that shows me the
>   stored variables

**There are varios IDEs for XQuery that come up with a Debugger. For example, have a look at [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xquery_debugger.html)**.

Answer (score 3):

As Dimitre suggested, trace() is what I fall back on when nothing else works. Messy but it works.

Instead of:
$foo := anyXqueryExpression

Do this:
$foo := trace(anyXqueryExpression, "text")

Logs the result of executing anyXqueryExpression and adds the prefix "text".

Answer (score 1):

There are few Xml Database centric diagnostics apis. 
w.r.t to MarkLogic Xml Database.

1. Diagnostics/ TaskServer UI in the
   admin console.
2. Tabular Profile use their CQ
   application
3. xdmp:query-trace(), xdmp:trace() are
   api gives some idea about the Query
   plan.
4. opensource Xquery Debugger =
   [xqdebug](http://code.google.com/p/xqdebug/)

are few techniques to have effective coding.