# How to debug XQuery

Tags: debugging, xquery

I am new to XQuery. Can anyone explain how the debug process happens in XQuery?

For example, how to debug the below declaration:

```
declare
  %rxq:produces('*/*')
  %rxq:POST
  %rxq:path('/sstatement/(Report)/([^/]+)')
function ReportSupplement(
  $supplementType
, $submissionId
)
```

Please suggest any site for debugging XQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to debug xquery program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830288/how-to-debug-xquery-program)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical way to debug queries in XQuery is to use the [trace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-trace) function around expressions of interest, like a call to the function above in your case.

For example:

```
for $i in trace(1 to 3, "s")
return <element>{$i * trace($i, "i") }</element>
```

and to read the output in a separate log, documented by your engine.

In this case, it will look like:

```
s[1]: 1
i[1]: 1
s[2]: 2
i[1]: 2
s[3]: 3
i[1]: 3
```